# Accessing Windsor IoC container

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have an object that I would like to access the Windsor Container. I have done this by registering the container with the container itself. Like so:

```
public class WindsorContainerInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
  public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
  {
    // no idea if this is a good idea or not
    container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(container));
  }
}

public class Foo
{
  public Foo(IWindsorContainer container)
  {
    _container = container;
  }
  private IWindsorContainer _container;
}
```

I haven't seen any examples with anyone doing it this way. I tend to see examples with people accessing the container by a static class or a singleton class.

So my question is. Are there any issues registering the container with the container itself?

**Update**

The scenario is perhaps not as simple as my initial code suggests. If my object had a particular dependency I would specify that in the constructor, like this `public Foo(IBar bar)`.

In this scenario Foo doesn't entirely know what dependency it needs.

```
public class Foo
{
  public Foo(IWindsorContainer container)
  {
    _container = container;
  }
  private IWindsorContainer _container;

  public void Add<T>(T entity)
  {
    var bar = _container.Resolve<IBar<T>>();
    bar.Create(entity);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes - [Service Locator is an Anti-Pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Whether you reference the container statically or through the constructor, you are creating *coupling* with the DI container and making an application that is *more difficult to configure* by burying the required dependencies deep in the code instead of making them available through the constructor.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I think my situation may be a little more complicated then I made it out to be. I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility.md Take care to Release everything you Resolve, even when using a factory.

Comment: It's not unheard of to [register the container itself](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectioninASP.NETWebAPIwithCastleWindsor/), but its usually done for specific edge cases.  You might want to open a new question explaining what Foo is supposed to do and why you feel registering the container is the solution (which, as @NightOwl888 pointed out, is an anti-pattern). Windsor is pretty flexible when it comes to resolving objects. It may already support what you need.

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have seen this in Framework code, an example is NancyFx https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Bootstrappers.Windsor/blob/master/src/Nancy.Bootstrappers.Windsor/WindsorNancyBootstrapper.cs#L85. Another example is in Factory classes. When people do this they must release the objects when done with them.

Comment: Does the FAQ explain it sufficiently? https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#why-wont-windsor-inject-itself-iwindsorcontainer-into-my-components